# Not presenting Safari view on click of Google sign in button

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am clicking on the google sign in button but it is not presenting the SafariView, but the delegate methods of GIDSignInUIDelegate is called.
Besides this the delegate methods of GIDSignInDelegate are not called from the App Delegate .

What are the possible reasons? Below is the code given:

My URL Scheme:

[com.googleusercontent.apps.1028134765971-6ok9n9pemgs3709q70so3bn5u08e84f6](http://com.googleusercontent.apps.1028134765971-6ok9n9pemgs3709q70so3bn5u08e84f6)

**AppDelegate.h**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  ESO
//
//  Created by BBI USER 1027 on 23/05/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 BBI. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
         signIn?.clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID!
        signIn?.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]
        signIn?.delegate = self
        return true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            print(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                    annotation: [:]))
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: [:])
    }

    //MARK :  Google sign in delegate methods
    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
                withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            // ...
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        // ...

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // ...
                return
            }
            // User is signed in
            // ...
        }

    }
}
```

**FBGoogleSigninViewController.swift**

```
//
//  FBGoogleSigninViewController.swift
//  LoginModule
//
//  Created by Shubham Ojha on 8/4/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 BBI. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class FBGoogleSigninViewController: UIViewController,GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var segmentView: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginIDCustomTextField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordCustomTextField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginIdLabel: UILabel!
    // On click of this button I am not getting any response.
    @IBOutlet weak var SignInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self;
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
        self.SignInButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func segmentValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        let segment = sender as! UISegmentedControl
        if segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                self.loginIdLabel.text = "Login ID"
            self.SignInButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }
        else{
            self.loginIdLabel.text = "Email ID"
            self.SignInButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }

    // MARK: google sign in delegate methods
    public func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!){

    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!){
        print(viewController.description)
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you added google url scheme in info.plist->URL Scheme?

Comment: Yes I already had!

Comment: Any update on this issue? am facing the same issue aswell :(